# Почему не видно данных переданных через ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax

Пытаюсь передать методом ajax данные с одной страницы на другую. На приемной странице не могу отобразить данные. И вообще они должны так отображаться? Вот код страницы с которой отправляю данные.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Пост запрос через ajax</title>
</head>
<body>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.js"></script> 

<script>
  $.post(
      "/test3.php",
      {
        param1: "param1",
        param2: 2
      },
  onAjaxSuccess
);

function onAjaxSuccess(data)
{
  // Здесь мы получаем данные, отправленные сервером и выводим их на экран.
  alert(data);
}

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

На странице приемнике данные то ли не передаются то ли не могу получить. Вот код страницы приемника.

```
<?php 

echo "I get param1 = ".$_POST['param1']." and param2 = ".$_POST['param2'];
```

В обратном ответе в файле с которого отсылаю в алерте пусто. Помогите разобраться что я делаю не так.

Спасибо!!

Answer (score 0):

Разобрался сам. Проблема в том что на приемном файле не было закрывающей блок php   ?>

Надо было так

```
<?php 

   echo "I get param1 = ".$_POST['param1']." and param2 = ".$_POST['param2'];

?>
```